# how to access all multiarray $_POST in PHP

Tags: php

I have my code in HTML that is setting the arrays of the values to pass via POST but I don't know how to access them in the php file.

This is 'main.php':

```
<tr>
  <td><input name="item[0][item]" type="text" id="item" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="price[0][price]" type="text" id="price" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="order_date[0][order_date]" type="text" id="order_date" size="5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="item[1][item]" type="text" id="item" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="price[1][price]" type="text" id="price" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="order_date[1][order_date]" type="text" id="order_date" size="5" /></td>
</tr>
```

At 'next.php' where the HTML code is sent I have:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

which gives me:

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => item1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => item2
                )

        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 80.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 59.99
                )

        )

    [order_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [order_date] => 2016-05-01
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [order_date] => 2016-05-31
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **use a `foreach`** to iterate the properties like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $i=>$item) {
    $name = $item['item'];
    $price = $_POST['price'][$i]['price'];
    $order_date = $_POST['order_date'][$i]['order_date'];
}
```

If it's possible to change your HTML layout, I would recommend something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><input name="items[0][name]" type="text" id="item" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="items[0][price]" type="text" id="price" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="items[0][order_date]" type="text" id="order_date" size="5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="items[1][name]" type="text" id="item" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="items[1][price]" type="text" id="price" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="items[1][order_date]" type="text" id="order_date" size="5" /></td>
</tr>
```

This makes it much easier to access and iterate the item's properties:

```
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item) {
    $name = $item['name'];
    $price = $item['price'];
    $order_date = $item['order_date'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you have to set your table like this:

```
<tr>
   <td><input name="item[]" type="text" id="item" size="5" /></td>
   <td><input name="price[]" type="text" id="price" size="5" /></td>
   <td><input name="order_date[]" type="text" id="order_date" size="5" /></td>
</tr>
```

and then iterate the $_POST like this:

```
$i = 0;
$totalNum = 2;
while ($i <= $totalNum) {
    echo "item: ".$_POST['item'][$i];
    echo "price: ".$_POST['price'][$i];
    echo "order date: ".$_POST['order_date'][$i];
    $i++;
}
```