# How to access input elements that are inside a div in an html file using php

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="grade_calculations.php" method="post">

    <div class="row">
    <!--
    Container
    -->
    <div class="col-md-4">

            Homework Percent: <input type="text" name="qTwo" value="%"><br><br>
            <div id="inputHW" class = "hw">
                HW 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
            </div>
```

I want to access the HW 1 input using php. I tried using $_POST['myInputs[]'] and I get an undefined index error. I get the same error when I try to access the homework percent $_POST['qTwo'].

```
echo $_POST['myInputs[]'];
```

I was wondering how do I access these elements?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How are you retrieving / outputting these `$_POST` variables? Can you please update your question to include your PHP?

Comment: `echo $_POST['myInputs[]'];`, yeah that would error out alright.

Comment: I'm not gonna answer a question that has been answered a lot of times before. `myInputs[]` is converted into an array, since `myInputs` is the name perhaps you should `var_dump($_POST['myInputs'])` to know how to access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access all multiarray $\_POST in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488575/how-to-access-all-multiarray-post-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

`$myInputs[]` is an array, if you want to access it you could use:

```
foreach ($_POST['myInputs'] as $key => $value) {
   echo $value . "<br />";
 }
```

If you see the variable $myInputs without  `[]`,it is because PHP will automatically convert this variable into array

Another way is:

```
$myInputs =  $_POST['myInputs'];
echo $myInputs[0]; //$myInputs[index]
```

Now, if you try access in this way:

```
echo $_POST['myInputs[]'];
```

You will get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: myInputs[] in.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array. Please do a better search before asking questions, I'm sure there are many answers to this.

```
$myArray = $_POST["myInputs"];

for ($count=0; $count<count($myArray); $count++)
   { echo $myArray[$count]."<br>"; }
```